# Dynamic Programming Optimal "Non-Decreasing Sequence"

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The question says,

Given an array A with N integer numbers, output the minimum number of operations needed to make the sequence non decreasing.

An operation represents choosing a number in the array A[i], summing it to A[i + 1] or A[i - 1], and deleting A[i]

The link to the problem ( spanish ): https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/Torres#problems

Example:

```
3
5 2 1

Answer: 2
```

In this case we must join all the numbers, to turn the sequence to { 8 }, which is non-deceasing

Limits:

```
N <= 5000
A[i] <= 10^5
```

I think this problem can be solved using DP, but i can't discover a state that can represent the problem in a small and correct way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean sort the array? Pretty sure that's given by *Quicksort* - or the ideal case, where the pivot point is always the median. But that depends on what you mean by *operation*, and "joining" two numbers.

Comment: What is 'joining two numbers'? Replacing two neighbor numbers with their sum?

Comment: maybe not dp...

Comment: @DAle using google translate, it seems to mean "summing"

Comment: Joining means replacing two neighbor numbers with one new number, represented by the sum of both

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: **I was wrong.**. The following algorithm doesn't solve the problem.

It can be done in one linear scan from left to right. Let me explain my reasoning:

If you join two numbers `A[i]` and `A[i+1]`, the result is greater than `A[i]`. If the part left of A[i] is already non-decreasing, this operation is necessary if `A[i] < A[i-1]`.

Unnecessarily joining `A[i]` and `A[i+1]` consumes an operation and makes things more difficult right of the join, so we do it only if necessary.

- If `A[i] < A[i-1]`, join `A[i]` and `A[i+1]` until `A[i] >= A[i-1]`.
- If `A[i] >= A[i-1]`, increment i.

P.S. The original problem description states that `A[i]` is in the range `1...10^5`, thus explicitly excluding negative numbers, which is important for the algorithm.

Comment: This solution is greedy. I believe there are test cases in which this idea is not the optimal

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this gives the optimal solution in linear time. Tell me if you find a counter-example ;-).

Comment: One more step, if you cannot make `A[i] >= A[i-1]`, then you should merge `A[i-1]` and `A[i]`

Comment: The counterexample is in the problem description: `8 2 7 3 1`.